# Entry with decimal with only two digits after point

Tags: python, database, window

I have Entry widget so I only allow floating point numbers. I'm using Validate. Now, I would like to block the digit number after the decimal point at 2. how then please? Thank you in advance for your time

> ```
>        def is_number(data):
>             if data == '':
>                 return True
>             try:
>                 float(data)
>                 print('value:', round(float(data), 2))
>             except ValueError:
>                 return False
>             return True
> ```

```
        # Les paramètres suivants ne peuvent être effectués qu'après la création des widgets et des rappels.
        vcmd = frame.register(is_number)
        Input_gr['validate'] = 'key'
        Input_gr['validatecommand'] = (vcmd, '%P')
```

Comment: if your ruby version is 1.9 or above you can use round method for example (50.68235534).round(2) ==> 50.68

Comment: if you want to use sprintf  check this link https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf    ==>  # precision for `f' is number of digits after the decimal point  ==> sprintf("%.2f", 1234.56789)  output is 1234.57

Comment: for python : 13.949999999999999                                                                                >>> print("%.2f" % round(a, 2))
13.95
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(a))
13.95
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(round(a, 2)))
13.95

Answer (score 0):

the goal is to display ex: 15.26 directly in the entry widget